# Install "Daedalus Wallet??"

Tags: command-line, tag

I need to know how to tell ubuntu that I want to install Daedalus Wallet, I need the command prompt wording please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have downloaded a file from https://daedaluswallet.io/en/download/.

From a terminal, navigate to the folder that contains the downloaded file, e.g.:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
```

Your download is an executable file, and so in principle you could install the program by entering the name of the file as a command. However, for security reasons, after downloading it doesn't have the "executable bit" on. So make it executable first:

```
$ chmod +x daedalus-4.2.1-mainnet-18759.bin
```

(Filename is what my downloaded file was called).

Then execute it:

```
$ ./daedalus-4.2.1-mainnet-18759.bin
```

That should do it. Mind that you can use auto-complete on long filenames such as these: type enough letters and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

`$ ./daed`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

`$ ./daedalus-4.2.1-mainnet-18759.bin`

Comment: Hi Jos, Thank you very much for your time and help, I appreciate itI I got Daedalus to install and open. I'm new to Ububtu and was used to "other" lesser OS's that were easier but window-y... not a fan. Thanks again, from a fellow musician. Bob

Comment: Thanks. If my post was helpful, please click on the tick mark next to it, to mark the question as answered.